# Whatss App like notification icon creation

Tags: android, notifications, android-icons

I would like to create whats app like notification icon

Please help me by givings `tips / suggestions / websites` for the creation of icon like that

Comment: First, it's hard to understand what you're talking about and what you're trying to achieve. Second, you want people to make more efforts for your project than you've done.

Comment: hi (Ego)r, thanks for reply...........I am trying to achieve is that i just want a cool icon for my app....You dont know what i have made and my efforts. If you dont have solution then patiently wait for some suggestions from other. I am not asking people to make an icon for me ...i am just asking for their help and i know they are not rude like you !!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you learn photoshop, and start with a tutorial like this:
http://designresourcebox.com/best-76-photoshop-icon-tutorials/

Then learn how to do this style here
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeeKbWl3xSE